# Bibliography on Sharelatex: I've followed guidelines and it still doesn't compile

Tags: bibliographies

I've created a small bibliography for my project. The bibliography doesn't compile and I've followed the guidelines as stated by [this cite](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Bibliography_management_with_biblatex) and using a citation generator. Instead of posting my code I will share to you my [article](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/56047ab50a0801262694b4d6). I hope you can tell me what are my mistakes via this website.

Thanks.

edit:

By the way, I'm not trying to create an in-text citation. Just include appropriately formatted references at the end of my article.

Comment: You should add a key for each bib entry, like `@article{key,` and not `@article{,`

Comment: This still doesn't work. By the way, I'm not trying to create an in-text citation. Just include appropriately formatted references at the end of my article.

Comment: Then add `\nocite{*}` to have all bib entrys in your bibliography or choose which one you want with `\nocite{key}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a bibliogaphy at the end of your document you need to

1. cite bib entrys or to use command `\nocite{*}` to have all bib entrys in your bibliography or use `\nocite{key}` to get the bib entry with key `key`into your bibliography.
2. your bib file has no keys defined for your entrys. So please add a key for each bib entry, like `@article{key,` and not `@article{,`.